# Browser Displays HTML Code from Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Have seen many similar problem but decision did not found.

**Problem**: Browser show code of servlet instead of perform this servlet.

Here is index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="servlets/LoginServlet.java"> Link </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is LoginServlet

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: give the servlet structure?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsw2t27petncbry/structure.png

Comment: ok i will post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,your path is giving you a problem

Html

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="../LoginServlet"> Link </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>package_name.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Dont forget to restart the server.**

Comment: This worked because he is having the package under the webapp folder it just took it to the root folder thats it

Answer (score 2):

```
 <a href="servlets/LoginServlet**.java**"> Link </a>
```

:P

You have mapped /LoginServlet in web.xml but are pointing to the source code in the a link.

Map your link to the right URL, the one you have in your web.xml in:

```
<url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
```

So the link must be:

```
<a href="/LoginServlet" >Link </a>
```

And so, the final URL will be be something like:

http:/localhost:8080/LoginServlet

Answer (score 1):

File **LoginServlet.java** . Chage **doPost** to **doGet** .

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html>\r\n");
        out.print("<head><title></title></head>\r\n");
        out.println("Hello World");
        out.print("</html>\r\n");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

File **index.jsp** . Change hyperlink to **"/LoginServlet"** .

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/LoginServlet">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**File web.xml**: Missing end tag: `</web-app>` . Correct file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

You should put java code in to **src** directory like this:
[image]

(put java code in **web** directory is very bad, by convention and security)

In next other cases, you should **put Servlet in to a package**.

Comment: I created package and change doPost to doGet but still have the same problem..
this is the project structure https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsw2t27petncbry/structure.png

Comment: @G.F. , you download source code project, unzip and open with your IDE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3iaa2xzvtpytym/untitled.rar

Answer (score 1):

Your url pattern you specified is `<url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>` that means the your valid url is `<a href="/ProjectName/LoginServlet"/>`

One more thing as you specified `<servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>` that means you dont have any package so make sure the class is directly under the `src` folder.

What I recommend is create a package put your servlet class inside it and change

`<servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>` to

`<servlet-class>packageName.LoginServlet</servlet-class>`

Comment: i did it but still have the same problem.
this is the project structure 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsw2t27petncbry/structure.png

Comment: @G.F Please drag out your servlets package from the webapp folder and put it in src folder it will run.Please note that your business codes dont come under the webapp folder.